# É possível utilizar $_POST dentro de sha1? ou outro tipo de criptografia?

Tags: php, post, md5, sha1

Estou fazendo comparação de formulários usando o sha1 da seguinte forma

```
sha1($_POST['txtEmpresa'] + $_POST['txtFornecedor'] + $_POST['txtDocumento'] + $_POST['txtValor'] + $_POST['txtVencimento']);
```

Existe alguma maneira de reduzir este código para ficar parecido com isto?

```
sha1($_POST);
```

ou outra forma de criptografia que atenda esta necessidade? já utilizei `md5` e também não deu certo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a [função `implode()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php), mas tenha cuidado com a variável `$_POST` pode conter parâmetros que você não queira e isso acarretaria em erro.

Exemplo:

```
sha1(implode('', $_POST));
```

Comment: "pode contar parâmetros que você não queira", não entendi muito bem poderia me explicar? estou usando assim sha1(date('Y-m-d H:m') + implode('', $_POST)) baseado na sua indicação e funcionou.

Comment: Imagine que no futuro você precise adicionar mais um campo no formulário que envia estes `POSTS`, como ficaria a comparação com o outro `sha1` que já foi criado anteriormente sem este campo? percebe que pode haver uma diferença? essa é basicamente uma das preocupações, mas se isso resolveu já fico feliz!
não esqueça de marcar a resposta como resolvido :)

Answer (score 3):

Uma possibilidade é você serializar o conteúdo de $_POST:

```
sha1(serialize($_POST));
```

E uma vez que você está comparando o valor de dois formularios, talvez seja interessante usar um **ksort($_POST)** antes de gerar o sha1 para garantir que a ordem dos campos seja igual já que isso pode alterar o valor do hash.